# jQuery: how to edit css when window height is a certain number?

Tags: jquery

```
var logoTop = (($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())*.5);
$("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
```

This script vertically centers `#logo` by taking the height of the window, subtracting the height of `#logo`, dividing by 2 and making that the `margin-top` for `#logo`. Works beautifully except when the window height is smaller than the logo height. Then it makes the `margin-top` a negative number and truncates the logo.

How can I make it so that when the window height is less than or equal to the height of `#logo`, the `margin-top` is simply 0?

EDIT (ADDED IF-ELSE STATEMENT) but not working on window resize event

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $("#logo").fadeIn(1000);
    var logoTop = (($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())*.5);
    if (logoTop < 0){
        ("#logo").css("margin-top","0");
    } else {
        $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var logoTop = (($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())*.5);
        if (logoTop < 0){
            ("#logo").css("margin-top","0");
        } else {
            $("#logo").css("margin-top",logoTop);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `if` statement:

```
if (logoTop < 0) {
    logoTop = 0;
}
```

Comment: Which works great on page load but I can't seem to incorporate it into the window resize event. It does work on resize when the window is initially bigger than the logo but if the window loads smaller than the logo then the logo is always stuck with a 0 `margin-top`.

Comment: The logic is the same. What are the values of `$(window).outerHeight()` and `$("#logotop").height()` when it doesn't work?

Comment: Look at my edit in the original post and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. I used this instead `logoTop = 0` and it works on resize. The css edit command for some reason didn't work on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
var logo = Math.max((($(window).outerHeight() - $("#logotop").height())*.5), 0)
```